# Disable Push Notification after New Installation of app without login

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have situation like this I am logging into the app then i am sending the device token to the server and i am getting the push notifications. If the consumer logs out from the app then i am sending a request to the server then i am not getting the push notification. If the user uninstall the app after logging in then i can't send a request to the server to stop the push notification then I install the app again but i didn't login then automatically I'm getting the push notification.

So my problem is how to stop the push notification when the user didn't login to the app

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but it might help someone.

I faced a similar situation in a project of mine:

## The problem

1. First run gets the device token
2. user logs in and the app registers the device token with the server
3. user uninstalls the app without logging out hence the server still thinks it's active
4. user reinstalls app, and still receives push notifications even though they're not logged in yet

In my app I register and request for the device token in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
       ..
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
       (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
       ..
}
```

And once the reply is received from Apple:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)token{
        //Get trimmed device token
        NSString *deviceToken = [[token description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        //Store the device token in the user defaults
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"dToken"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
 }
```

This is more or less the typical way I've seen it done.

Now when the user logs in, the device token is sent to the server and registered from the main view controller of the user content area. The device token is retrieved by accessing the user defaults from within that view controller. The problem however is if the user never logs in to the user content area, the notifications will still persist because the device was never unregistered with the server as a result of the previous uninstall while still logged in.

## The Solution

There are a few approaches to solving this problem as mentioned in other answers. However I didn't want to modify my server and the main structure of registering devices there, which goes something like:

- When the user first logs in: authenticate the user and register the passed device token at the same time.
- When the user logs out: unregister the device token to that user.
- Whenever a device token exists in the DB: deactivate it for all users except for the user currently logging in.

Seeing that the user content area must have the device token to log in the user, I start by requesting the device token in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** as I did before.

Now when a reply is received in **didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken** I do the following:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)token{
        //Get trimmed device token
        NSString *deviceToken = [[token description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
        deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        //Store the device token in the user defaults
        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userDefaults setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"dToken"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];

        //If not logged in yet, unregister for notifications
        if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loggedIn"])
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
 }
```

I check if the user content view controller has not been reached yet, i.e. the user never logged in, and disable the notifications.

In the user content view controller I do the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    ..
    //Set logged-in so the notifications continue to be received
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loggedIn"]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"done" forKey:@"loggedIn"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        //Register for notifications (again)
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    //Send user authentication and device token (retrieved from the user defaults) to server
    ..
}
```

Now whenever the user first logs in the device token is sent to the server and registered without any delays because it has already been retrieved from Apple. The notifications are also disabled until the user logs in and therefore the main problem is solved.

This approach insures that the user content area view controller is never loaded without the device token saved in the user defaults and therefore allows me to continue using the same method of authenticating the user and passing the device token at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify when the app is launched for the first time (either after the first time it's installed or after being uninstalled and re-installed) by storing some data locally on your device (for example, you can store the device token).

When the app is launched for the first time, send the device token to your server in a request that would clear any DB entry that refers to that device token (the same request you send to your server when a user logs out). This way your server wouldn't send push notification to this device token until a user logs in.

The next time a user logs into the app, send the device token & the user id to your server in a request to start sending push notifications for that user using that device token.

Comment: where do i register for push notifications after login or didfinish launch application

Comment: It doesn't really matter. If you choose to register after login, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will send the device token with the user id to your server. If you choose to register in didFinishLaunch, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will store the device token locally in your app, and after a user logs in, you send the device token with the user id to your server.

Comment: actually me also doing the same but, my problem is user logs in and without logs out the user may uninstall the app in that case i can't send a request to the server. so, the server keep sending notifications then i didn't get any notification because the app isn't installed. Now reinstalled again the server keep sending the notifications in this case I'm getting the notifications without logging so now i suppose to stop the notifications until the logs in

Comment: Oh, my comment doesn't match my answer. In order to follow my the suggestion in my answer, you must register for push notifications each time the app is launched. Then, in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, you should check if you already have a stored value of the device token on your device (you can store it, for example, in NSUserDefaults]). If you don't, make a service call to your server that will delete the device token from your DB (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

I like this situation...Check my logic.

**Fist important thing you have is that when the app uninstalled,its database also gets vanished**.
this is the trick.

==>You have to maintain a reference number which start from 1.
(you may put it hard coded and only have to update)
use this reference number each time with your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//get value from database,increment  by 1
//sync with server
}
```

each time app gets started you have to increment the reference number also.
need to keep track of this reference number on server side also.

**Second scenario(i.e. problem you facing) is when app gets reinstalled:
all database gets vanished automatically.==>this is the trick**

**when you use reference number next time from database it will be 1.**

Now compare it with server-side.

After second scenario that is after app gets reinstalled your reference number will be less than current maintained one i.e(**1< current maintained reference number @server**)
this is the condition to know server that app is reinstalled and need to wait till authentication.

so make server to disallow notification for current device till login by user.and after successful login update all database and allow server to send notification.

Comment: It is little confusing me I'm unable to understand the solution

Comment: insert dummy table i.e fixed value containing reference number as 1 and each time read it and update to +1 while launching app in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method